# POST data through AJAX and set as variable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am not very familiar with javascript especialy when it comes to functions and ajax. I am trying to get some data from another php page and have it put into a div. When I ever i load the page nothing comes up.

My ultimate goal is to get the data into a php or javascript but first need to figure out how to get / receive data.

here is the php code of feedupdate.php

```
    <?php
require "dbc.php";

    $function = $_POST['function'];

    switch($function)
    case('initiate'):
    $search="SELECT * FROM Feedtest ORDER BY id DESC";
    $request = mysql_query($search);
    $mostrecent= mysql_fetch_array($request);
    $mostrecentid = $mostrecent['id']
    echo json_encode($mostrecentid);
     break; 


    case('update'):
    $search="SELECT * FROM Feedtest ORDER BY id DESC";
    $request = mysql_query($search);
    $update= mysql_fetch_array($request);
    $updateid = $update['id'];
    echo json_encode($updateid);
     break;          
?>
```

here is the ajax

```
<div id="datacheck"></div>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function()  {
     $.ajax({
          type: 'POST'
          url: 'feedupdate.php'
          data: {'function': 'initiate',},
          datatype: "json"
          success: function(msg) {
              $('#datacheck').html(msg);
          }

        });
  }); // document ready
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in the ajax jquery code

> success: fuction(msg) {...

it should be spelled "function".This typo might be the problem , plus there should be switch case for

> getState

in your php code.

Comment: can you check your javascript console in your browser for any possible client side errors ?

Comment: Also if you are using chrome , use this extension to test out your POST request http://getpostman.com

Answer (score 1):

In your AJAX you are passing data back to the PHP script:

```
data: {'function': 'getState'},
```

But in your php script you don't have a case statement that matches `getState` you only have `initiate` and `update`. So you can either write code to support `getState` or you can pass in either `initiate` or `update` to the data parameter.

Also watch out for trailing comma's.  They won't work in IE.  You should remove the comma after `'getState'` on the data line.

You are also missing a comma after `type`, `url`, and `datatype`

```
  $(document).ready(function()  {
     $.ajax({
          type: 'POST', // add comma
          url: 'feedupdate.php', //add comma
          data: {'function': 'initiate'}, // remove comma
          dataType: "json", // add comma
          success: function(msg) {
              $('#datacheck').html(msg);
          }

        });
  });
```

Alos you can look at using the shorthand method `$.post` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: i put initiate but still nothing, any ideas?

Comment: missing commas need to be added

Comment: ok added commas, console says "unexpected identifier" for the json I'll look that up.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `getState` in data from JavaScript  while in PHP you do not have a similar case to match in `switch` statement. Instead of `getState` pass `update` or `initiate`.

If you just want to check either AJAX call is working or not write

```
echo "something message"; exit();
```